# Django to Wagtail: How to list my apps in the dashboard

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

I just followed [this](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/getting_started/integrating_into_django.html) guide to convert my django project to wagtail. I have some applications there already (blog, portfolio etc). Now when I accessed the wagtail admin panel I didn't see the applications. Please how is this done in wagtail?

Answer (score 1):

Wagtail is not a drop-in replacement for the Django admin. The closest equivalent is the [ModelAdmin module](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/modeladmin/index.html), but in general, Wagtail is intended for building *new* content-management features into your site [as described in the tutorial](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/getting_started/tutorial.html), not converting your existing site functionality.

Comment: Oh thanks for the clarity, it's really helpful.